# How to get a field from spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

MODEL

```
@Column(name="id_usr_adm_tkn")
private int id;

@Column(name="npp_usr_adm_tkn")
private String npp;

@Column(name="jbtn_usr_adm_tkn")
private String jabatan;
@Id
@Column(name="username_usr_adm_tkn")
private String username;

@Column(name="password_usr_adm_tkn")
private String password;
//describes the tables in the database
@Column(name="email_usr_adm_tkn")
private String email;

@Column(name="nm_adm_usr_tkn")
private String nama;

@Column(name="ktk_adm_usr_tkn")
private String kontak;

@Column(name="sts")
private int sts;

@Column(name="id_wlyh")
private int id_wlyh;
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username_usr_adm_tkn,password_usr_adm_tkn, sts from adm_tkn_tebel where username_usr_adm_tkn=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from roles where username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I can retrieve username from spring security use a step like this

```
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
                String admin = userDetail.getUsername();
```

The problem is that I can't get other fields such as "**id_wlyh**" ? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create you own authentication provider

```
 <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="myprovider" />
 </authentication-manager>
```

the class will look like this :

```
@Component("myprovider")
public class MyProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userdao;

    @Override
    public void additionalAuthenticationChecks(final UserDetails arg0, final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Nothing
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(final String username, final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        MyUser u = userdao.getUser(username);
        if (u != null) {
            return u;
        }else{
            throw new BadCredentialsException("user invalid");
        }
    }

}
```

You have to create your user class adding as many field as you like:

```
public class MyUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
}
```

Then when accessing the principal you can cast it to your own definition :

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
MyUser userDetail = (MyUser) auth.getPrincipal();
```

This way you will have access to any data you want

Comment: sorry i do not understand at @Autowired private UserDao userdao;
if I had to make a class userDao ?please explain in more detail

Comment: I am getting this error when running program "No bean named 'myprovider' is defined"<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
 <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query=
     "select username_usr_adm_tkn,password_usr_adm_tkn, sts from adm_tkn_tebel where username_usr_adm_tkn=?"
    authorities-by-username-query=
     "select username, role from roles where username =?  " />
     
  </authentication-provider>
  <authentication-provider ref="myprovider" />
 </authentication-manager>

Comment: UserDao is a class you will have to create to check in database if the user exists. If the bean myprovider is not found make sure it is in you compentScan, otherwise declare the bean in the xml instead of using the @Component annotation :<bean id="myprovider" class="...."/>. In your authentication manager use only one authentication provider remove the old one

Comment: I have followed your instructions but I get an error as above,
if there is not appropriate based on your suggestions?I was very ordinary,
I need all the help you

Comment: it looks like spring doesn't find your class so declare in your spring-security.xml : <bean id="myprovider" class="my.full.package.MyProvider "/>

Comment: @Zia I've rolled back your edit please don't edit the answer to comment.